# Equality of perturbed Ramanujan's sum and -1/12

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, problem-solving, divergent-series

Consider the series $\sum_{k=1}^n k e^{-\varepsilon k}\cos(\varepsilon k)$. If one lets $\varepsilon$ be small enough (for example 0.0001) and $n$ large enough (for example 1.000.000), one sees by numerical computations that this sum will converge to $-\frac{1}{12}$. See also https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/MATLAB/Divergent_series_investigations or test it by yourself using any programming language.

Besides this rather interesting fact, my question is now how to solve $\varepsilon$ in terms of $n$ in the following equation $$\sum_{k=1}^n k e^{-\varepsilon k}\cos(\varepsilon k)=-\frac{1}{12}.$$ If one solves this, one can for example obtain sufficient conditions in order to apply zeta function regularization in areas where is made a lot of use of perturbed series (such as physics).

I tried to integrate both sides of the expression (w.r.t. $\varepsilon$) but arrived at no interesting relationships so far. Maybe one does have heard of this expression, knows more about it or even know how to solve it for $\varepsilon$?

See also my slightly related question [Closed form expression for (periodic) generalized harmonic numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3049601/closed-form-expression-for-periodic-generalized-harmonic-numbers) which might provide clearer insights.

Comment: Today's Ramanujan's bday btw ;)

Comment: Hey yeah, I see! Nice coincidence :D!

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n k e^{-x k}2\cos(x k) =\frac{d}{dx} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{1+i}e^{-x (1+i) k}+\frac{1}{1-i}e^{-x (1-i) k}) = \frac{d}{dx}( \frac{1}{1+i}\frac{1-e^{-x(1+i)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-x(1+i)}}+\frac{1}{1-i}\frac{1-e^{-x(1-i)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-x(1-i)}}) = ...$

Comment: I see that actually $\frac{1}{6}=-\sum_{k=0}^n 2ke^{-xk}\cos(xk) = \frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{1+i}\frac{1-e^{-x(1+i)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-x(1+i)}}+\frac{1}{1-i}\frac{1-e^{-x(1-i)(n+1)}}{1-e^{-x(1-i)}})=-(\frac{(n+1)e^{x(-i-1)(n+1)}(1-e^{x(-i-1)})-e^{x(-i-1)}(1-e^{x(-i-1)(n+1)})}{(1-e^{x(-i-1)})^2}+\frac{(n+1)e^{x(i-1)(n+1)}(1-e^{x(i-1)})-e^{x(i-1)}(1-e^{x(i-1)(n+1)})}{(1-e^{x(i-1)})^2})$. I don't know how to reduce it to an expression in which we can solve it for $x$ however...